# Pandas - list of numerous conditions, with logical operator, used with 'select' statement

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

and can't seem to find a solution.

Please help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


t = np.arange(0,100,1); t = pd.Series(t)
y = np.random.randint(1,20,100); y = pd.Series(y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': t,'y': y})
mean = np.mean(df['y'])
st_dev = np.std(df.y)

conds = [(df['y'].values > mean + 3*st_dev), (df['y'].values < mean - 3*st_dev),
         (df['y'].values <= (mean + 3*st_dev) and (mean - 3*st_dev) <= df['y'].values )]
choices = [1,0,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `and` working with scalars, here is necessary `&` for bitwise `AND` and also is necessary add `()` because priority operators:

```
conds = [(df['y'].values > mean + 3*st_dev), (df['y'].values < mean - 3*st_dev),
         (df['y'].values <= (mean + 3*st_dev)) & ((mean - 3*st_dev) <= df['y'].values )]
choices = [1,0,2]

df['new'] = np.select(conds, choices)
print (df)
     t   y  new
0    0   4    2
1    1   2    2
2    2  13    2
3    3   8    2
4    4  14    2
..  ..  ..  ...
95  95   5    2
96  96  10    2
97  97   8    2
98  98   6    2
99  99  16    2

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```